# Помогите с реидректом htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

нужноо сделать чтобы со страницы сайта /mainАбркакадвара перемещало на главную страницу
например: 
с /main - на главную 
с /mainsfsdf - на главную
c /mainShdghsadf на главную
спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не лучший вариант так-как использует абсолютный URL:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/main(.*)$ http://example.com/
```

Здесь 301 код редиректа (moved permanently, см. значения HTTPшных кодов состояния в [русской вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#3xx)). http://example.com/ — адрес на который будет перенаправлен посетитель.